# Как сделать редирект на любой URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как перенаправить клиента на новую страницу при помощи JS/jQuery?
<sup>[Перевод вопроса "How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/6275986)</sup>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### jQuery для этого не нужен!

Способов несколько:

1. **`location.href`** - это свойство объекта [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location), у которого [сеттер](https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters) отправляет страницу на новый адрес и изменяет историю (кнопка "Назад", история браузера).

   ```
   window.location.href = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com'; // Переход на ruSO
   ```
2. [**`location.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) - метод, который **заменяет** текущую страницу.
   Т. е. без изменения истории.

   ```
   window.location.replace('https://stackoverflow.com'); // Переход на SO без изменения истории
   ```
3. [**`location.assign`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) - метод направления в светлое будущее, его использует `location.href`:

   ```
   window.location.assign('https://stackoverflow.com'); // Переход на SO с изменением истории
   ```

Если **очень** хочется использовать `jQuery`, то Вам нужно <s>лечится от хуквери-зависимости</s> просто изменить `location.href`:

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com'); // Отправляемся по адресу
```

---

**Важно:** Если скрипт, который пытается инициировать перенаправление, находится на стороннем домене, то будет брошена ошибка `DOMException` с типом `SECURITY_ERROR`.