# Как переправить пользователя на другой адрес?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли используя js  или jQuery переправить пользователя на другую страницу?

Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать редирект на любой URI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640996/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-uri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно средствами `javascript` обойтись:

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
window.location.href("http://google.com");
```

Если нужен `jQuery`:

```
$(location).attr("href","http://google.com");
```

Comment: спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1):

За текущий URL страницы на чистом JavaScript отвечает объект window.location.

Поменять адрес страницы можно либо напрямую изменением свойства

```
window.location.href = 'http://ya.ru';
```

или с помощью метода assign:

```
window.location.assign('http://ya.ru');
```

При обоих этих способах будет работать кнопка назад в браузере (если вдруг потребуется вернуться на предыдущую страницу).

Если же не нужно сохранять в истории посещений страницу, то можно воспользоваться методом:

```
window.location.replace('http://ya.ru');
```

Он заменит содержимое текущей страницы на указанную и не сохранит прошлый адрес в истории.